# Adobe Air - Using encryption with SQL databases or EncryptedLocalStore?

Tags: encryption, air

I need to store 6 sets of passwords and usernames with Adobe Air 2.5
Should I use a SQL database or the EncryptedLocalStore for it?

Thanks. Uli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how the information will be acquired and then used. If it's info that an application user provides, and it's then being cached for future use, EncryptedLocalStore (ELS) could be a good way to do it. There are some benefits and limitations:

- ELS is designed to hold small amounts of data - your example of 6 user/pw combos qualifies.
- ELS data is available to all processes accessed by a particular user. So after being set in one application, it can be accessed from other AIR applications from the same publisher as long as it's the same user as authenticated by the operating system. If you don't like this access model, you should use a database instead.
- ELS Data shouldn't be considered to be permanent - it can be deleted in a number of ways. You should provide a way for users to re-enter the data if it's no longer available.

Check the docs at http://goo.gl/Nd3gQ for more info on when and how to use ELS.